# rasdial fails with "This network connection does not exist."

Tags: windows, powershell, vpn

I am trying to connect to a VPN on my machine with `rasdial`, but it keeps failing with `This network connection does not exist.`:

```
# Admin pwsh
> rasdial MYVPN-Manual
Connecting to MYVPN-Manual...
Verifying username and password...This network connection does not exist
```

How can I fix this?

### Further info

```
> Get-VpnConnection | select name

name
----
Another VPN
MYVPN-Manual
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** this answer seems incorrect. The confounding part was that I connected to the VPN *via the Action Center UI* between trying with/without the quotes.

---

<del>You need to put quotes around the VPN name (because it seems to have special characters):</del>

```
> rasdial "MYVPN-Manual"
Connecting to MYVPN-Manual...
Verifying username and password...
Registering your computer on the network...
Successfully connected to MYVPN-Manual.
Command completed successfully.
```

[rasdial documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/ff859533(v=ws.11)):

> If the ConnectionName contains spaces or special characters, use quotation marks around the text (that is, "Connection Name").

Comment: Were you able to find out what's going on? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Good question! Unfortunately, there appear to be some newer VPNs that can only be activated through the UI (as in, there's no tool that can activate them & no public API).